# magento default total return with decimal currency

Tags: magento-1.9

please help me how to change the decimal to comma in the currency of magento. Right now it is showing by default like this >> Total: € 590.9000 (It is calling the default total function of magento) rest is working fine and coming with commas, is it possible to change the default decimal value to comma. Thankx in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "number_format" method of PHP to convert default decimal value to comma.
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_number_format.asp